# Explicit Euler method

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I am looking to find the explicit and implicit codes for Euler's method. In my search I am across the following code, I am wondering if this code is explicit? if not how could I change it to make it so?

```
import math
# First Order ODE (y' = f(x, y)) Solver using Euler method
# xa: initial value of independent variable
# xb: final value of independent variable
# ya: initial value of dependent variable
# n : number of steps (higher the better)
# Returns value of y at xb.
def Euler(f, xa, xb, ya, n):
      h = (xb - xa) / float(n)
      x = xa
      y = ya
      for i in range(n):
          y += h * f(x, y)
          x += h
      return y
print(Euler(lambda x, y: math.cos(x) + math.sin(y), 0, 1, 1, 1000))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code implements the *explicit* Euler scheme.

In order to be implicit, there would be an instruction like

```
y = solve(z == y + h*f(x,z), z)
```

in the inner loop, where `solve(equation, variable)` is a suitable function to solve an equation (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method)).

Comment: how would I add a step size to this code?

Comment: The step size is `h`, which is currently controlled by the argument `n`

Comment: so what do I need to replace that line of code you have in my code?

Comment: You need to implement the code that finds the fixed point in the implicit Euler scheme. You can either use a fixed-point iteration, or a generic nonlinear solver, such as https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding

Comment: either way, thanks for your help!